# How to find files by the time in their filename?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, date

We have a directory contains files which contains time in their filename

```
./test.2013-06-11_06-01.gz
./test.2013-06-12_01-01.gz
./test.2013-06-13_03-01.gz
./test.2013-06-14_03-01.gz
./test.2013-06-15_04-01.gz
```

How to list files if their filename are more than **N days** before?

Comment: What does `06-01`, `01-01`,... mean?

Comment: @Gnouc - could it be the time? in the date_time format...

Comment: Does the file create/modify time reflects the same date than the filename?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
maxdate=$(date -d "5 days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d");
for fn in *.gz; do
    [ "$fn" ">" "test.${maxdate}_99-99.gz" ] || echo $fn
done
```

I'm ignoring the part of the filename after the date (time, presumably?), but it would be fairly easy to modify this to consider that part of the filename as well if needed.

This answer is based off of a similar question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443078/filtering-filenames-with-bash

Comment: What is the magic "99-99" in your scripts?

Comment: @Howard, I didn't know what the last two numbers in the filename were for, so I used the max value for those in order to get consistent behaviour. If I had omitted them or used `00-00`, filenames that exactly matched the date we got for "5 days ago" would have been skipped because `"test.2013-06-12_01-01.gz" > "test.2013-06-12"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date` command to find date of N days before, then using `grep` to search in your text file.

```
grep `date +%Y-%m-%d -d "5 days ago"` test.txt
```

test.txt:

```
./test.2013-06-11_06-01.gz
./test.2013-06-12_01-01.gz
./test.2013-06-13_03-01.gz
./test.2013-06-14_03-01.gz
./test.2013-06-15_04-01.gz
```

ouput:

```
./test.2013-06-15_04-01.gz
```

Today is 20/06/2013, 5 days ago is 15/06/2013.

**Update**

The final solution, I use a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
tmp="/tmp/tmp_$$.txt"
tmp1="/tmp/tmp1_$$.txt"
maxday=$2

cp $FILE $tmp

for i in `seq 1 $maxday`
do
    date_point=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$i days ago"`
    grep -v "$date_point" $tmp > $tmp1
    cp $tmp1 $tmp
done

echo "Files match:"
cat $tmp
rm -rf $tmp
rm -rf $tmp1
```

This script will remove all file N days ago upto now from output, so if you want to find all file older than N days, you must define `maxday = N - 1`, i.e if you want to file that older than 8 days:

```
./test.sh test.txt 7
```

Ouput:

```
Files match:
./test.2013-06-11_06-01.gz
./test.2013-06-12_01-01.gz
```